# how to specify values for a key using a value from another key in another object in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection "users" and let's say there are two objects "user1" and "user2", each users has fields avatar, friends, name and possibly other fields.

The main part of my question

In the "user2" object in the "friends" field (this is an array) there is an object {name: user1, avatar: db.users.user 1.avatar}
as you already understood, I need to have a link to avatar user1 in this object in the avatar field, I wrote incorrectly, just to make it clear what I want to do.

user1 : {
avatar : "link on avatar",
name: "user1",
friends: []
},

user2 : {
avatar : "link on avatar",
name: "user1",
friends: [{name: "user1", avatar: ??? }]
}

where the question marks need to insert a link to the avatar user1

I need to do this in mongodb, without using node js

I have no idea how this can be done. I need to do this in mongodb, without using node js

Answer (score 0):

you can save the objectId in the friends array and then do a $lookup

```
db.users.updateOne(
  {_id: new ObjectId("2")},
  {
    $push: {"friends": new ObjectId("1")}
  }
)

db.users.aggregate({
  $lookup:{
    from: "users",
    localField: "friends",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "friends"
  }
})
```

result:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("1"),
    avatar: '1',
    name: 'user1',
    friends: []
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("2"),
    avatar: '2',
    name: 'user2',
    friends: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("1"),
        avatar: '1',
        name: 'user1',
        friends: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array